# Angular2 .subscribe sometimes does not fire the router.navigate

Tags: angular

I've a login function:

```
login(user: UserComponent) {
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user.username + ":" + user.password)); 
return this._http
  .get(
    'https://api.xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/rest/auth', 
    { headers }
  )
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    (data) => {
      this.loggedIn = true;
      console.log('data '+ this.loggedIn);
      localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
      localStorage.setItem('auth_token', data.token);
      console.log(data.token);
      this._router.navigate(['']); 
    },
    (err) => {
      this.errorMsg = err.json().error_message
      console.log(this.errorMsg);
    }
  );}

isLoggedIn() {
    if(this.loggedIn){
      return true;
    }else{    
      this._router.navigate(['login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

that I call like this:

```
   constructor(private _userService: UserService, private _router: Router) {}

authUser() {
  let user = new UserComponent(this.username, this.password);
  this._userService.login(user);
```

}

the CanActivate goes like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

  canActivate() {
    console.log(this._userService.isLoggedIn());
    return this._userService.isLoggedIn();
  }

}
```

**UPDATE #1**
I think I found the problem, but don't know how to solve. I updated the code above with the current version.

Looks like the problem is when it performs the action the Guard runs before the this.loggedIn is set to true.... returning false yet... why? how do I fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You login function is **asynchronous** and that is why `console.log` happening before you get data from your service. You need to **wrap** `console.log` in you **login** function to see data

```
this._userService.login(user).subscribe(
  (data) =>{
    this.data = data
    console.log(this.data);
   },
(err) => this.errorMsg = err.json().error_message);
```

Comment: Thank you, but like I said above "the data or error always come right at the console.log, but the this._router.navigate(['']); sometimes fires but most of the time does not...", I've tried to add it there too but nothing changes, in fact now it never fires.. but the console always return the object...